# Fibonnacci sequence is giving segmentation fault at the count of the 50th number in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fibonacci

My program is supposed to count the x'th line of fibonnacci sequence, if the x passed in the execution is under 50 it works fine , but from 50 and above i get a segmentation fault.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t fibonnacci ( uint64_t n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    else {
        uint64_t * val;
        val = malloc ( sizeof ( uint64_t )*2);
        val [0] = fibonnacci (n -1);
        val [1] = fibonnacci (n -2);
        return val [0] + val [1];
    }
}
int main ( int argc , char * argv []) {
    printf ( " % llu \ n " ,fibonnacci ( atoi ( argv [1])));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code! Looks like you're leaking memory as you're not freeing anything after malloc. And the malloc code is dubious to me -- You're assigning to val like it's an array, but it isn't.

Comment: Segmentation faults are a great opportunity to drop this into a debugger and see where it fails, then step through the code again up to the point of failure while carefully observing the behaviour.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating an array of two numbers? Why are you even assigning those to variables? `return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)` is equivalent and doesn't leak memory.

Comment: I see you `malloc`ing and not freeing.  Not sure why `malloc` is being used, frankly.

Comment: Did you check if `malloc` is actually giving you the memory in return - `if(!val)`? or `free` the memory?

Comment: Where is the call to `free()`? You need to release resources!

Comment: Small point about readability: you don't need an `else` after `return`.

Comment: `return  fibonnacci(n-1)+fibonnacci(n-2);`

Comment: Compile with `gcc -O3` and it works without crashing :D (you just need to wait)

Comment: Why oh why are you using malloc?

Comment: This would be why recursion should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

A segmentation fault usually means you're trying to access a null pointer.

Calculating the fibonacci sequence of 50 results in millions of recursive calls, and every time you allocate 16 bytes for val, but you never free that memory when you're done with it. Eventually you use up all your memory. `malloc` is unable to allocte more for you, so it returns NULL. When you try to store something into the memory address NULL you get a segmentation fault.

Instead of using `malloc` you should, in this case, just store the two values on the stack by declaring a local array or just two variables. The stack is automatically deallocated when the function returns

Answer (score 0):

My compilation crashes at `Fibonacci 39`.

If I add a call counter to the recursive function, `Fibonacci 38` calls the recursive function `126491971` times.

You are not `free`ing the memory, and you do not check the return value from `malloc`. So you can run out of memory at some point, depending on the implementation.

When I use the code suggestion by @RedaMeskali I can run `Fibonacci 50` although it takes at least one minute to run.

Fibonacci might be a useful exercise for learning recursion, but is a very inefficient. In a simple loop, `Fibonacci 50` can be computed [in a trice](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trice).